# Are there plans to create some education or certifications on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, badges, jobs

A lot of people hate this question... so I'll try to reword it.

Has Stack Overflow considered moving into an educational capacity that leads to something tangible like a certification?

The certification would be one that SE markets (perhaps at conferences) to businesses that helps to indicate developer competence.

For instance, you could have a C++ course and certificate, which would essentially show that others appreciate your insight in C++.  One of the requirements for certification could be in contributing answers to C++ section of SO.  SE could partner with a company like [Pearson VUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_plc#Pearson_VUE) to reaffirm someone's skill via a subject matter test.  I see certifications such as CISSP, CCNA, etc in the "nice to have" section of job listings.  Why can't SE have a cert?

Comment: Isn't this just tag badges?

Comment: Good question.  Thanks.  I probably didn't word it very well.  I feel like badges will never be seen in a job listing.  I just think that maybe there could be a subset of badges that could be branded as certifications by being perhaps a prerequisite to a written exam or perhaps a stand alone.  I don't want to suggest too many specifics as I want to hear others' creative thoughts too.

Comment: Some people consider SO rep valuable! This was discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271008/would-you-consider-stack-overflow-reputation-valuable-at-interviews

Comment: Yeah.  I guess.. I'm curious if there are(or should be) plans to make SO involvement more tailored to the hiring process.  I thought a certification would speak to the language of many people in HR.  It's a silly idea.  I can see that it's not well received.  Perhaps for many good reasons.

Comment: Legitimate certification comes from properly accredited institutions, in some countries claiming to be a member of certain professions is illegal (Doctor, Engineer, etc.); you can't just make up things and expect them to be widely accepted. --- Places that aren't properly accredited are called a [mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accreditation_mill). --- It's much like there being people who can drive without a driver's license, they may even drive well when drunk, there's a reason that it's illegal; in practice it has been found to be dangerous.

Comment: Wow... a lot of people hate this question.  Feel free to delete it as it doesn't seem researched, useful, or clear.  People have spent time answering this question... but I don't think this question will be useful to others.  I'll stay away from SE meta.

Comment: Voting on meta includes upvoting/downvoting to agree/disagree with a post's proposal, not just the post quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines does exist already but it's limited to Stack Overflow as it's offered through the [Stack Overflow Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join)

Stack Exchange has [partnered with Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/newsroom/press-releases/pluralsight_and_stack_overflow_partner) to offer skills tests within your developer story for some popular programming languages and those languages/tests are associated with the relevant Stack Overflow tags so you can show your proficiency via your tag score too.

[Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pluralsight-iq) has a tag [pluralsight-iq](/questions/tagged/pluralsight-iq) that has questions about this integration.

Clearly this is aimed squarely at your next job rather than conferences but it does address your last paragraph, i.e it's displayed somewhere that a prospective employer might take note of it.

In theory this could be rolled out to other sites if they ever became big enough to justify it.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that Pluralsight's *test* is ~10 minutes long and [consists of **20** questions](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/what-is-pluralsight-iris-and-iq). An actual Final Exam at a recognized post secondary [can exceed three hours](https://senate.universityofcalifornia.edu/bylaws-regulations/regulations/rpart3.html#r770), while [in some cases you may have as little as 90 minutes](https://berkeleycollege.edu/pdf/credit-for-prior-learning-guide.pdf). A Challenge Exam is of identical difficulty (though not a duplicate) to a course's final exam. [continued]

Comment: [continuation] --- As a manager (or employer) I wouldn't accept Pluralsight's test, would Stack Exchange accept it; not based on their interview process.